# Pandoc Lua Filter: Is there an 'identity function' example?

Tags: lua, abstract-syntax-tree, pandoc

Is there is an equivalent of the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) for [Lua Filters for Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) available anywhere?

This would be a useful starting point for experimentation, assuming such an identity transform explicitly defined all possible function 'slots'.

For context: my use-case here is to extract specific parts of Markdown documents - mostly codeblocks - and I want to ignore everything else.

Comment: There are quite a lot of possible "slots": you can match on all of the pandoc document AST's types of nodes (blocks and inlines) See https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-pandoc

Comment: Thanks - I saw that - my main use-case here is to extract specific sections - code blocks for instance - but I want to reject the majority of other parts of the AST - basically, looking for a fancy 'grep'. I'll add more detail to my original post.

Comment: I think I am thinking about it the wrong way  - looks like the filter can 'divert' matched output  - using "pandoc.pipe" mechanism.
Or at least that is how I understand it now - looking at the code in this example: https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/spellcheck/spellcheck.lua

Comment: that's quite a sophisticated example. I'll post something in an answer...

Comment: I actally got it working in lua :)

Comment: Just tried it on my Markdown - works brilliantly - thanks! I guess the main trick here was to overload the Pandoc function itself ! I'm going to slightly edit your answer to include the cmdline needed to run this - since it might be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity transform for the `Strong` element:

```
return {
  {
    Strong = function (elem)
      return elem
    end,
  }
}
```

Or if you don't need multiple filter runs, you can do the shorthand:

```lua
function Strong(elem)
  return elem
end
```

You can return `nil` for elements that you want to filter out. For example removing all `Strong` elements would be:

```lua
function Strong(elem)
  return nil
end
```

But there are quite a lot of different elements.

So perhaps what you should do is do `pandoc -t json` and pipe that to a program in your favourite programming language and extract all code blocks. See [pandoc filter tools](https://pandoc.org/filters.html#but-i-dont-want-to-learn-haskell) for some packages, but if you're only interested in code blocks at the top level (and you don't need to recursively walk the tree), then no package should be needed.

But it's true, you can achieve the same thing with a lua filter:

```lua
local codeBlocks = {}

return {
  {
    CodeBlock = function (el)
      -- on each CodeBlock match,
      -- append to codeBlocks like it's an array
      table.insert(codeBlocks, el)
    end,
    -- on the next run, we simply return a new
    -- Pandoc document with the code blocks
    Pandoc = function()
      return pandoc.Pandoc(codeBlocks)
    end
  }
}
```

Example usage (assuming filter code is in 'filter_codeblock.lua', and markdown document is 'main.md')

```
pandoc --lua-filter filter_codeblock.lua main.md -t markdown
```